# Python: how to get display aspect ratio from video?

Tags: python, opencv, video, aspect-ratio

I have a video where ffmpeg tells me a storage aspect ratio (SAR) of 4:3 but a display aspect ratio DAR of 16:9. Resolution is 1440x1080.
Is there any chance to find out that DAR of 16:9 with Python-OpenCV or any other package?

Answer (score 3):

*Storage Aspect Ratio* is the ratio of the image width to height in pixels, and can be easily calculated from the video file.

*Display Aspect Ratio* is the ratio of image width to height (in a unit of length such as centimeters or inches) when displayed on screen, and is calculated from the combination of Pixel Aspect Ratio and Storage Aspect Ratio.

SAR × PAR = DAR.

For example, a 640 × 480 VGA image has a SAR of 640/480 = 4:3, and if displayed on a 4:3 display (DAR = 4:3) has square pixels, hence a PAR of 1:1. By contrast, a 720 × 576 D-1 PAL image has a SAR of 720/576 = 5:4, but is displayed on a 4:3 display (DAR = 4:3).

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_aspect_ratio)

So, using OpenCV you can get the SAR (ratio of pixel Dimensions ) but I doubt that you can get a *constant* display aspect ratio from it (since it is display dependent).

What you could do is when [displaying](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563) the image, you can get [window property](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#gaeedf4023e777f896ba6b9ffb156f57b8) which has a flag **WND_PROP_ASPECT_RATIO**.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this works for most videos (requiring ffprobe which ships with ffmpeg)

```
import subprocess
import json
def get_aspect_ratios(video_file):
    cmd = 'ffprobe -i "{}" -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams'.format(video_file)
#     jsonstr = subprocess.getoutput(cmd)
    jsonstr = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True, encoding='utf-8')
    r = json.loads(jsonstr)
    # look for "codec_type": "video". take the 1st one if there are mulitple
    video_stream_info = [x for x in r['streams'] if x['codec_type']=='video'][0]
    if 'display_aspect_ratio' in video_stream_info and video_stream_info['display_aspect_ratio']!="0:1":
        a,b = video_stream_info['display_aspect_ratio'].split(':')
        dar = int(a)/int(b)
    else:
        # some video do not have the info of 'display_aspect_ratio'
        w,h = video_stream_info['width'], video_stream_info['height']
        dar = int(w)/int(h)
        ## not sure if we should use this
        #cw,ch = video_stream_info['coded_width'], video_stream_info['coded_height']
        #sar = int(cw)/int(ch)
    if 'sample_aspect_ratio' in video_stream_info and video_stream_info['sample_aspect_ratio']!="0:1":
        # some video do not have the info of 'sample_aspect_ratio'
        a,b = video_stream_info['sample_aspect_ratio'].split(':')
        sar = int(a)/int(b)
    else:
        sar = dar
    par = dar/sar
    return dar, sar, par
```

----------- Old Answer--------------------------

```
import subprocess
import json
cmd = "ffprobe -i D:/out.mp4  -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams"
jsonstr = subprocess.getoutput(cmd)
r = json.loads(jsonstr)
a,b = r['streams'][0]['display_aspect_ratio'].split(':')
dar = int(a)/int(b)
print(a, b, dar)
```